# SSRS DateTime Format - set to US not UK

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, bids

I currently have a reporting services report created in BIDS 2005 and the database is SQL Server 2008 R2. My first issue is when I'm in BIDS and go to preview to test the report it only processes with the date in us format mm/dd/yyyy however if I deploy the report to the report server and run it from there it is fine.

I have changed the report properties to language English(United Kingdom), is there anything else I can do to get my reports to preview in English date format dd/mm/yyyy when in BIDS/VS?

My second and final issue with this is that when I try to create a schedule for this report it also errors as I pass in 2 date parameters (datetime) in the standard SQL format of yyyy-mm-dd using the data driven option. This also runs only if these dates are in US format, any ideas/tips?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a while I have finally found a solution to my data driven subscription (DDS) date issue. Apparently for DDS the settings within the server is used rather than the report settings so I checked the database settings by using SQL Server Management Studio and right clicking the database then selecting properties, I then checked the language settings and hey presto its set to English(United States) how I got around this was to convert my date into a format that was non language dependant -

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) – yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm

This worked and fixed my DDS :)